# How to read in a text file to R using textConnection and library(sqldf)

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a text file into R so I can use the sqldf functions.  I'm following this example, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-January/152040.html, but I have a text file holding my data instead of the data being pasted as the example has it.   My text file is below:

```
#"test.table.1.0" file has this contents:
id  Source
1     A10
2     A32
3     A10
4     A25
```

I tried this following the example

```
test_table <- read.table(textConnection("test.table.1.0"))
```

I can see that the problem is that textConnection is supposed to take a character vector, 
and I'm giving it a data.frame, but converting it via as.character also fails.  Ultimately, I want to run a query like this:

```
sqldf("select test_table.source from test_table");
```

Comment: How about `read.table(file="test.table.1.0")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aniko's comment has almost all you need (along with `header=TRUE`):

```
R> data <- read.table("test.table.1.0", header=TRUE)
R> data
  id Source
1  1    A10
2  2    A32
3  3    A10
4  4    A25
R>
```

In other words, if you have the data in a file, read from a file. A textConnection is useful if and when you have the data 'right there' along with the command as in the email you referenced.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize the function of textConnection.  I also had an extra comment in my SQL, now removed.

Answer (score 6):

One can go directly into SQLITE using read.csv.sql() OR read.csv2.sql() from the sqldf package.

From the online manual:

[Link](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_13._read.csv.sql_and_read.csv2.sql)

> Example 13. read.csv.sql and
>   read.csv2.sql read.csv.sql is an
>   interface to sqldf that works like
>   read.csv in R except that it also
>   provides an sql= argument and not all
>   of the other arguments of read.csv are
>   supported. It uses (1) SQLite's import
>   facility via RSQLite to read the input
>   file into a temporary disk-based
>   SQLite database which is created on
>   the fly. (2) Then it uses the provided
>   SQL statement to read the table so
>   created into R. As the first step
>   imports the data directly into SQLite
>   without going through R it can handle
>   larger files than R itself can handle
>   as long as the SQL statement filters
>   it to a size that R can handle. Here
>   is Example 6c redone using this
>   facility:

```
# Example 13a. 
library(sqldf) 

write.table(iris, "iris.csv", sep = ",", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE) 
iris.csv <- read.csv.sql("iris.csv",  
        sql = "select * from file where Sepal_Length > 5") 

# Example 13b.  read.csv2.sql.  Commas are decimals and ; is sep. 

library(sqldf) 
Lines <- "Sepal.Length;Sepal.Width;Petal.Length;Petal.Width;Species 
5,1;3,5;1,4;0,2;setosa 
4,9;3;1,4;0,2;setosa 
4,7;3,2;1,3;0,2;setosa 
4,6;3,1;1,5;0,2;setosa 
" 
cat(Lines, file = "iris2.csv") 

iris.csv2 <- read.csv2.sql("iris2.csv", sql = "select * from file where Sepal_Length > 5")
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're data is not all that big, read.table() works great. If you have gigs of data you may find read.table or read.csv to be a little slow. In that case you **can** read data directly into sqlite from R using the sqldf package. Here's an example:

```
library(sqldf)
f <- file(“test.table.1.0”)
bigdf <- sqldf(“select * from f”, dbname = tempfile(),
   file.format = list(header = T, row.names = F))
```

A few months ago I wrote a [personal anecdote about my experience using this method](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2009/11/loading-big-data-into-r/).

In my experience pulling data directly into sqlite is a LOT faster than reading it into R. But it's not worth the extra code if a simple read.csv() or read.table() works well for you.