# load huge file and compute row and column sums in R

Tags: r

I am trying to load a huge file into R (>30 Gb).

The commands I am trying to run are not only slow but they also crash the ram:

```
m = read.table("myfile.txt")
print("Done reading m")
m.row.sums = apply(m,1,sum)
write.table(m.row.sums, file = "myfile_rowsums.txt")
m.col.sums = apply(m,2,sum)
write.table(m.col.sums, file = "myfile_colsums.txt")
m.sub = m[,which(m.col.sums>1000)]
write.table(m.col.sums, file = "myfile_sub.txt")
```

Is there a more more memory efficient (and faster) way to achieve the same in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791396/how-to-read-huge-csv-file-into-r-by-row-condition

Comment: BTW you could use `rowSums`/`colSums` instead of `apply(m,1,sum)`/ `apply(m,2,sum)`.

Comment: R has no real piping capabilities... So if you run out of RAM, and you can't delete any variables, then you are out of luck... (as far as i know)