# Load a small random sample from a large csv file into R data frame

Tags: r, csv, random, dataframe, bigdata

The csv file to be processed does not fit into the memory. How can one read ~20K random lines of it to do basic statistics on the selected data frame?

Comment: One [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532810/reading-40-gb-csv-file-into-r-using-bigmemory/18282037#18282037)

Answer (score 25):

You can also just do it in the terminal with perl.

`perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .01)' biglist.txt > subset.txt`

This won't necessarily get you exactly 20,000 lines. (Here it'll grab about .01 or 1% of the total lines.) It will, however, be really really fast, and you'll have a nice copy of both files in your directory. You can then load the smaller file into R however you want.

Comment: nice, any way to keep the csv header?

Comment: @pomber you could first copy the header line (e.g. `head -1 file.txt > sample.txt`) and then run the perl operation with `>>` instead to append

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Python?

Comment: For Windows you'd need to change the `'` to `"`

Comment: Tried this using a csv as the bigFile, but it copied the whole file.

Comment: I tried with windows and csv and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Try this based on examples 6e and 6f on the [sqldf github home page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf):

```
library(sqldf)
DF <- read.csv.sql("x.csv", sql = "select * from file order by random() limit 20000")
```

See `?read.csv.sql` using other arguments as needed based on the particulars of your file.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
RowsInCSV = 10000000 #Or however many rows there are

List <- lapply(1:20000, function(x) read.csv("YourFile.csv", nrows=1, skip = sample(1, RowsInCSV), header=F)
DF = do.call(rbind, List)
```

Comment: is it as fast as via Perl?

Comment: Doubt it. Takes about 6 seconds on my machine, so it doesn't really make a difference unless you have to do it all the time.

Comment: could it be that the arguments in the sample function are inverted? sample(RowsInCSV, 1)? Furthermore, I think a bracket in the end of the lapply command is missing.

Answer (score -4):

The following can be used in case you have an ID or something similar in your data.
Take a sample of IDs, then take the subset of the data using the sampled ids.

```
sampleids <- sample(data$id,1000)
newdata <- subset(data, data$id %in% sampleids)
```

Comment: Not at all helpful if, as OP says, "The csv file to be processed does not fit into the memory".