# Read a reproductible sample of data from multiple CSVs

Tags: r, csv

I'm working with several large CSV files, large enough that I can't efficiently load them into memory.

Instead I would like to read a sample of data from each file. There have been other posts about this topic (such as [Load a small random sample from a large csv file into R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261082/load-a-small-random-sample-from-a-large-csv-file-into-r-data-frame) ) but my requirements are a little different as I would like to read in the same rows from each file.

Using `read.csv()` with `skip` and `nrows=1` would be very slow and tedious.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to efficiently load the same N rows from several CSVs without reading them all into memory?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18282037/489448 for reading the file in chunks.  Now in that answer the random sample is chosen as the chunks are read; if you do the random sampling once outside the reading loops you can use the same sample for all your files.

Comment: There is an option ```colClasses``` in ```read.csv()```. If that is not provided, then the whole column is read, and the class for each column is determined after that. So, if all the classes are known then ```read.csv()``` will comparatively be quick. Also, you can specify any integer to ```nrows``` and it'll read the specified number of rows from top.