# Subsetting while reading in R

Tags: r, date, file-io, subset

I have a 5+ million rows in R with just 4 cols per row. One of the columns is the date when the data was collected. An example is

```
Date        PI   SSC    GC
2/11/2013 0.52  0.89   4.2
2/11/2013 0.56  0.45  12.0
2/11/2013 0.49  0.89  13.1
2/11/2013 0.59  0.47   4.8 
2/11/2013 0.61  0.58  12.3
```

I would like to know if there is a way to read ONLY certain rows corresponding for certain dates, rather than having to read the 5 million rows and then subsetting. For example, all rows corresponding to the date 2/11/2013 (I do not know how many are in the file). Also, in case it's of any help, the class of the Date column is factor.

Comment: Other possibly relevant answers [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532810/reading-40-gb-csv-file-into-r-using-bigmemory/15798275#15798275) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094866/trimming-a-huge-3-5-gb-csv-file-to-read-into-r?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not exactly an answer to what user asks, but 5 mil rows are not really too much to read. Ofcourse base R's `read.table` will be very slow but using `fread` from `data.table` package is fast enough. Here are the benchmarks

```
tbl <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, text='Date        PI   SSC    GC
2/11/2013 0.52  0.89   4.2')

require(data.table)
#create hige datatable with 5mil rows to write to temp file
bigtbl <- rbindlist( lapply(1:(5*1e6), function(x) tbl))
write.table(bigtbl, row.names=F, quote=F, file="temp.txt")


#benchmark of reading 5 mil row file back using fread function
system.time(bigtbl2 <- fread('temp.txt'))

## Read 5000000 rows and 4 (of 4) columns from 0.116 GB file in 00:00:11
##  user  system elapsed 
##  10.76    0.08   10.86
```

Ofcourse memory size may still be concern, but in this case it's only 153MB still

```
> tables()
     NAME         NROW  MB COLS           KEY
[1,] bigtbl2 5,000,000 153 Date,PI,SSC,GC    
Total: 153MB
```

If you are going read this data frequently, it makes sense to save the data in standard RData file using `save` function and read it back using `load`