# Very large .csv file,

Tags: database, r, csv

I have large amount of Data, about 20 million rows and 6 columns. I am trying to extract data from this large .csv file.
I tried R, but i get error msg, I am using macbook with 4 GB Ram, i5 processor.
Is there any way I can extract information, 
I tried excel, it can take only 1 million rows.
any advise or help will be useful

file is more than 1.3 GB, i want to divide this data base into set of about 2000-3000 based on a parameter. I tried R and when I used read.csv.. i tries for a moment but but after 10 mints or so i get R not responding –

I want to separate these data based on 3rd column.

SHA    PCT PRACTICE    BNF CODE    BNF NAME

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094866/trimming-a-huge-3-5-gb-csv-file-to-read-into-r, in addition, right now your question lacks the required detail. Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: How big is the file and what do you wan't to do with the information from it?

Comment: What do you need to do. Extract some rows according to some criteria or process each row of the csv and then calculate some results?

Comment: 20 million x 6 columns x 8 bytes for double ~ 1GB, so it should fit easily. What have you tried?

Comment: @themel as a rule of thumb, R needs 3 times the amount of memory that is needed for the object because of copying and such, so 1GB is pushing it a bit, depending on what the OP is doing.

Comment: file is more than 1.3 GB, i want to divide this data base into set of about 2000-3000 based on a parameter. I tried R and when I used read.csv.. i tries for a moment but but after 10 mints or so  i get R not responding

Comment: post a reproducible example

Comment: can you post first 5 rows from the file? you want to subset based on 3rd column?

Comment: This can probably be done with a few lines of `awk`. `awk '$3="foo"' < data.csv >foo.csv` will select all lines with the third item equal to "foo". Learn some new tools.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you have to tell what do you mean by extract data. If it is some sort of aggregation functions or it can be divided, than I think that the easiest way is to split you huge csv file into many small one.

If you need something else, than have a look here:

- package for storing big data on the disk (not ram) http://ff.r-forge.r-project.org/
- package that allocates points to unused memory or points to a swap file. https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=556
- paralelizing big data http://www.r-bloggers.com/taking-r-to-the-limit-parallelism-and-big-data/
- few discussions here http://www.mathfinance.cn/handling-large-csv-files-in-R/ http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Read-a-Large-CSV-into-a-Database-with-R-td3043209.html

Answer (score 0):

I would dump it into a SQL database (mySQL,postgre,SQLlite and make a call using the ODBC driver that you can find in the RODBC package (JDBC also works).

You can then do a 'SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE column_3= X;'

Good luck!

[Link to tutorial[1](http://www.mathfinance.cn/any-good-way-to-import-large-CSV-file-into-mysql/)