# How to read first 1000 lines of .csv file into R?

Tags: r

I have very big .csv file, it's around a few GB.
I want to read first few thousand lines of it.
Is there any method to do this efficiently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094866/trimming-a-huge-3-5-gb-csv-file-to-read-into-r?rq=1

Comment: I came to this question repeatedly when looking how to solve the same issue. I'd  like to see solutions in readr read.csv etc. And from the number of hits, upvotes and favourites think it would be useful to reopen the question?

Comment: This is pretty valid question. Don't really understand why it is "too broad". Do we really need repex to write big csv just to have something to deal with? The nature of problem of reading just part of the file is broad, not the question.

Comment: Check out argument `nrows` in `help("read.csv")`.

Comment: I see no problem with this question at all.  It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 104):

Use the `nrows` argument in `read.csv(...)`

```
df <- read.csv(file="my.large.file.csv",nrows=2000)
```

There is also a `skip=` parameter that tells `read.csv(...)` how many lines to skip before you start reading.

If your file is that large you might be better off using `fread(...)` in the data.table package. Same arguments.

Comment: `skip` isn't very helpful if the first line is the row of column names.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg In that case you can `scan()` the first line with n=1, then use `read.csv` with `skip=` and add the colnames after that.

Comment: for `read_csv` (R 3.4.4, Win 7), the option is `n_max`, see docs (p. 6) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf

Comment: Example: `read_csv(file="train.csv", n_max=2000)`

Answer (score 20):

If you're on UNIX or OS/X, you can use the command line:

```
head -n 1000 myfile.csv > myfile.head.csv
```

Then just read it in R like normal.