# Read only first few lines of CSV (or any text file)

Tags: r

I often come across larger datasets where I don't know what they actually contain.

Instead of waiting for them to be opened in a conventional text editor or within the RStudio text editor, for example, I would like to look at the first few lines.

I don't even have to parse the contents, scanning these first few lines will help me to determine what method to use.

Is there a function/package for this?

Comment: There is an answer to your question here I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222113/how-to-read-first-1000-lines-of-csv-file-into-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.table` has an `nrows` option:

```
nrows: integer: the maximum number of rows to read in.  Negative and
      other invalid values are ignored.
```

so read in a few and see what you've got.

If you have a Unix environment then the command `head file.csv` will show the first ten lines. There are lots of other useful Unix commands (guess what `tail file.csv` does) and even if you are on Windows you could benefit from installing Cygwin and learning it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your question:

[How to read first 1000 lines of .csv file into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222113/how-to-read-first-1000-lines-of-csv-file-into-r)

Basically use nrows in read.csv or read.table...