# Import from a big file only one line at the time in R

Tags: r, parsing, readline

I have a very big text file that I cannot read in R with `read.table()` because of its huge size.
I know that with `readLines()` function you may specify how many rows you want to import, but I would need to import one line at the time in a for loop, and save it in a new file or store in a vector/list/whatever...

So, something that in `python` would be:

```
myfile=open("myfile.txt",mode="r")
for line in myfile:
    line=line.strip()
    line=line.split("\t")
    print line
```

Is that possible with R?

Comment: Why would you read it one line at a time in a loop? Have you looked at `fread` from the "data.table" package yet?

Comment: To occupy as less memory as I can..
I'll have a look right now! thank you !

Comment: How big is your file? You can use `colClasses`, `comment.char="", strip.white=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=F` in `read.table` or in deed use `fread` function from `data.table` which is extremely fast. Here is useful discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094866/trimming-a-huge-3-5-gb-csv-file-to-read-into-r

Comment: more thant 2 GB, that's why I would prefer a line-by-line approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [`scan()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scan.html) a try. Using `skip` you can skip already read lines and using `nlines` you can specify the number of lines you would like to read. Then you can loop through the file.

```
> large <- 10000
> m <- matrix(sample(c(0,1),3*7,replace=TRUE), ncol=3)
> write.table(m, "test.txt")

> for(i in 0:large) {
+     l <- scan("test.txt", what = character(), skip = i, nlines = 1)
+     if(length(l) == 0) break
+     print (l)
+ }

Read 3 items
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3"
Read 4 items
[1] "1" "0" "1" "0"
Read 4 items
[1] "2" "0" "0" "0"
Read 4 items
[1] "3" "0" "0" "0"
Read 4 items
[1] "4" "0" "1" "1"
Read 4 items
[1] "5" "1" "1" "1"
Read 4 items
[1] "6" "1" "0" "1"
Read 4 items
[1] "7" "0" "0" "1"
Read 0 items
```

The code serves the purpose of illustrating how to apply `scan()` and how to know when you have to stop reading.

Comment: Well, just in case, could I also print one line at the time in a .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

While Яaffael's answer is enough, this a typical use case for package [iterators](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/iterators.pdf).

With this package you iterate over the file, line by line, without really load all the data to memory. Just to show an example i will crack the [Airlines](http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html) data with this method. Get 1988 and follow this code:

```
> install.packages('iterators')
> library(iterators)
> con <- bzfile('1988.csv.bz2', 'r')
```

OK, now you have a connection to your file. Let's create a iterator:

```
> it <- ireadLines(con, n=1) ## read just one line from the connection (n=1)
```

Just to test:

```
> nextElem(it)
```

and you will see something like:

[1](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/iterators.pdf) "1988,1,9,6,1348,1331,1458,1435,PI,942,NA,70,64,NA,23,17,SYR,BWI,273,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA"

```
> nextElem(it)
```

and you will see the next line, and so on.

If you want to read line by line till the end of the file you can use

```
> tryCatch(expr=nextElem(it), error=function(e) return(FALSE))
```

for example. When the file ends it return a logical FALSE.